# Most common HTML templating language

Tags: javascript, html, template-engine

Simple question, but hard to google....

What is the most commonly used (or most "industry standard") HTML processing engine that lets me "include" "partials"?

Must also provide a single .js file that can be called with `<script>` inside an HTML file to include the partials if I don't want to use any more complex web frameworks or libraries like jQuery.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are thinking? Pseudo code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at http://underscorejs.org/ or http://mustache.github.io/ which has a JS version.

Note, underscore has a lot of functionality but is pretty small and has a "template" method for what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an industry standard one, but take a look at ECT - http://ectjs.com/.